# ubuntu14.04 installation

Tags: 14.04, system-installation

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 desktop i386.iso version (Intel) version but I am not shure
what version of Ubuntu 14.04 I need for installation on Intel Pentium D CPU 2.8Ghz x 2 and Grafics -> Gallium 0.4 on ATI RV370

Comment: Welcome to Askubuntu.com! Please rephrase your question: have you installed Ubuntu, or do you still want to install it? Your system should support 64-bits Ubuntu, if that is what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

Pentium D supports 64-bit versions of Ubuntu, so you could use either the 32 or 64 bit ISO.

Both should support your ATI GPU and offer you the ability to install various drivers after the install completes. Once you're booted, open the Dash and search for "Drivers". The "Additional Drivers" utility will install the needed video drivers for you, regardless of which ISO you use.